# Timeout while connecting to mongodb instance from kubernetes pod

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongo-shell

I set up a Kubernetes Cluster on Hetzner following theses steps: https://github.com/kube-hetzner/terraform-hcloud-kube-hetzner

```
Client Version: v1.26.3
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.26.4+k3s1
Mongosh Version: 1.8.1
```

I am unable to connect to either my own mongodb server (docker deployment) or a hosted one on `mongodb.net`:

```
root@trustsigner-frontend-deployment-59644b6b55-pqgmm:/usr/share/nginx/html# mongosh mongodb+srv://<removed-user>:<removed-password>@cluster0.fdofntt.mongodb.net/test
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6447807561ebcee04b00165d
Connecting to:          mongodb+srv://<credentials>@cluster0.fdofntt.mongodb.net/test?appName=mongosh+1.8.1
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

Same error when using my own one with `mongodb://` instead of `mongodb+srv//`.

But surprisingly it is possible to use the same connection string with mongodb compass or mongosh that is installed on my machine (not in a kubernetes pod)

Ping to 8.8.8.8 or to any other side works and I can fetch via curl. But no chance to establish a mongodb connection...

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar problem on a kubernetes cluster deployed with kube-hetzner. I guess this is a problem with some ports that are not opened/forwarded. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I switched to a native k3s and there it worked. So it seems to be a problem with the provided terraform approach

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to identify what was the issue. I am going to write an answer so that other people who fall here know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiencing the same issue while using [kube-hetzner](https://github.com/kube-hetzner/terraform-hcloud-kube-hetzner) as you, I looked at the configuration file and found the culprit: by default, outbound traffic is filtered, except for a few popular ports like HTTP or HTTPS.

There are at least 2 solutions:

1. you set the variable `restrict_outbound_traffic` to *false*:
   https://github.com/kube-hetzner/terraform-hcloud-kube-hetzner/blob/master/kube.tf.example#L395
2. You add a firewall rule to allow outbound traffic on port 27017.

Once done, the connection to a Mongo Atlas cluster is working perfectly!

Comment: Should have read the config file more carefully. Thank you for investigating!